# Multiple parameter in Get Method

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, webapi, getmethod

```
    [Route("api/LoginValues/itemcode/{username}/{password}")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<AC_Attendance> Get(string username, string password )
    {
        **var list = from g in db.AC_Attendances where g.username == username select g;**
        return list;
    }
```

[image]

How i want to make " g.username == username AND g.password== password "

Comment: What is the issue you are facing?

Comment: I have updated my question. .im still newbie with web API asp.net not sure how to handle this problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example I have taken employee(userID and password) as parameter.

```
public IEnumerable<Employee> Get(int Id, string password)
  {
     using (EmployeeDBEntities entities = new EmployeeDBEntities())
       {
           return entities.Employees.Where(tem => tem.ID == Id && tem.password 
                 == password).ToList();
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```cs
public IEnumerable<AC_Attendance> Get(string username, string password)
{
    var a = db.AC_Attendances
        .Where(s => s.username == username && s.password == password)
        .ToArray();

    if (a != null)
    {
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `if` `else` statement does not make too much sense. It does not alter the value of `a` just return it as it is.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).